# Differences in structure between an participle phrase and an participle clause

Tags: grammar, participle-clauses, participle-phrases

1. Removing his pants, Ron jumped into the water to save the child.
2. Walking down the street, I ran into an old friend.
3. Packing his baggage, he left his home and proceeded to cut all his ties
   with his former life.
4. Finishing his homework, Peter went to bed.

Some of the phrases function as adjectives and others function as adverbs. (based on different websites)
How you can recognize this?
[https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/c1-grammar/participle-clauses#:~:text=Participle%20clauses%20enable%20us%20to,having%20walked%2C%20etc](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/c1-grammar/participle-clauses#:%7E:text=Participle%20clauses%20enable%20us%20to,having%20walked%2C%20etc).
https://www.paperrater.com/page/participial-phrase

Comment: I don't know about 'functioning as adjectives or adverbs' (can you provide links to those websites?), but in (2) the sense is 'while doing so' and in the others 'after doing so'.

Comment: [*A phrase*](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-participle-clause-and-a-participle-phrase) *is a single part of speech. That means it's a bunch of words that have nouns or verbals (verb-like items) but NO SUBJECT. In short, a phrase doesn't have a subject-verb component. ... A clause is a group of words that do contain a verb and its SUBJECT.* I guess that means all your examples are [participial] *phrases*, since none of them contain a subject.

Comment: I mean, "Removing his pants", "Walking down the street", "Packing his baggage" and "Finishing his homework" are phrases in which 1 is adj, 2 is adv, 4 is adv and 3 I don't know. but I think they are all the same.

Comment: None of your examples, i.e. _"Removing his pants", "Walking down the street", "Packing his baggage"_ and _"Finishing his homework",_ is a clause.  Perhaps you need to clarify your question title.  The question appears to be interested in the difference between a participial phrase versus a clause, but a clause must include a subject and a verb, whereas none of the example expressions does.

Comment: Standing in the queue, I realised I didn't have any money. https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/c1-grammar/participle-clauses#:~:text=Participle%20clauses%20enable%20us%20to,having%20walked%2C%20etc.). What is "Standing in the queue" here? 
Biblasia

Comment: In what way is _removing his pants_ an adjective? It's just a way of saying that he took his trousers off before entering the water.

Comment: https://www.paperrater.com/page/participial-phrase 

Removing his pants, Ron jumped into the water to save the child.
The participial phrase functions as an adjective modifying ‘Ron’. Removing (participle) his pants (direct object of action expressed in participle). Kate Bunting

Comment: You need to put the @ sign before a person's name to make the system notify them of a message. Also, I asked you to provide the links to websites _in your question_.  I think the link provided by @Biblasia explains it better. (A _queue_ is what Americans call a _line_ - a row of people waiting for something.)